# no internet access with sudo

Tags: networking, fedora

My Fedora is installed in a VirtualBox and the host resides behind a firewall. The `Network Proxy` settings are correct. I know that because I can access the internet from Firefox.

The command `wget www.ibm.com` fetches the index.html just fine. But `sudo wget www.ibm.com` hangs and then tries after a timeout.

Executing `echo $http_proxy` return a string with `user:password@proxy.server.net`

Executing `sudo echo $http_proxy` also return a string with `user:password@proxy.server.net`

My real concern is to be able to run `sudo dnf update` but I guess the first step is to get `sudo` to have access to the outside world.

I tried to disable the checking of SSL certificates but it did not help:

```
sudo -E dnf --nogpgcheck update
```

yields

```
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora'
```

Comment: Please check the sudoers file on your linux based system.in sudoers file its clearly mention the permission of sudo.

Answer (score 5):

Try running with `-E` option to preserver environment.

```
sudo -E dnf update
```

Comment: thank you, the -E option resolved the issue with wget but running sudo -E dnf update still fails to sync

Comment: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-dnf-command-with-a-proxy-server-on-fedora/) might be useful to you.